# Algorithm for schematizing (metro) maps

Tags: algorithm, math, graph-algorithm

This is a long shot, but I thought I might try before starting the dirty work.

I've got a project to build an application which will, for a defined input stations (vertices) and lines (edges), that is, a real map of some public transportation, schematize a given map into a metro map. I've done some research on the problem and it's an NP-complete problem equivalent to the 3-SAT problem. I also have some theoretic ideas on how to generate such a map, but they aren't detailed enough.

What I'm looking for is any other existing solution of this problem, some sort of pseudo-code, some real code in (almost) any other programming language etc, anything that would reduce the time I need to spend working on the algorithm itself, which will in return give me more time to work on other aspects of the application.

If anyone has ever seen anything that can help me, I'd appreciate it very much.

Comment: "... for a defined input stations (vertices) and lines (edges), that is, a real map of some public transportation, schematize a given map into a metro map." In this context it is not clear what the difference between a "map" and a "metro map" is.  Can you provide an example?

Comment: You need to give more details about the different constraints of your metro map, like how station names should be displayed, how should stations where lines join/cross be displayed, how should two lines following the same path be displayed?

Comment: A normal map would be a map in which the relations between landmarks and places is conserved - that is, everything is scaled in proportions. On the other hand, a metro map doesn't preserve those proportions, but rather just shows relevant information in a visually appealing way.

At this very moment, it's not really important how the names or crosses would be displayed, I can always get to that later. Preferably, parallel lines would be displayed next to each other, but that's also an option, any base I can get my hands on will be good.

Comment: Anyway, I think you should edit your post trying to state apart real constraints and preferences. If all your constraints ARE only preferences an artist will do much better than a programmer :)

Comment: try to include the [@name] in your answers so the other part gets notified

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you google for "metro map layout problem" and "metro map line crossing" you'll find a lot of references, since it has been researched very actively in the past 10 years.

The problem seems no trivial at all, and translating the "artistic" features to mathematical constraints is seemingly one of the most difficult tasks.

Anyway here are three publications that I found interesting to start with (among many, many others):

[Metro Map Layout Using Multicriteria Optimization](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/pubs/2004/1925/content.pdf)

[Line Crossing Minimization on Metro Maps](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.114.6776&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

[The Metro Map Layout Problem](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.89.1137&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

HTH!

Comment: Considering the short time frame, we ended up implementing a very limited algorithm of our own, which was good enough for the project scope.

If anyone else is interested in this problem, this publication is a very good start:
http://www1.informatik.uni-wuerzburg.de/pub/wolff/pub/nw-dlhqm-10.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Research that's similar to your topic:  http://graphics.stanford.edu/papers/routemaps/

Answer (score 1):

This is just some suggestion with handwaving - take with a pinch of salt.

My notion of a "metro" map is one where lines tend to one of the eight cardinal directions and stations are regularly spaced.

I'm assuming you're trying to convert a set of real coordinates into "metro" coordinates.

I would start with your main route (e.g., a city loop), then incrementally add other routes in order of importance.

For each route you want to find the nearest approximation that uses the fewest number of straight lines travelling in the eight cardinal directions.  You might do this by starting with the bounding box for the real coordinates, splitting that into a grid, then finding a "metro" route from grid square to grid square, then successively refining that route to reduce the number of bends without distorting the map too much and without introducing crossings with other routes if at all possible.

Having done that, scale each line so that consecutive stations are the same distance apart on the "metro" view.

My guess is you'll still want to support manual tweaking of the result.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I had something like that in mind, including the manual tweaking. I was just hoping someone might have a bit of code to get me started, before I do it all myself.

Answer (score 1):

Feels like a planning problem.
Looks like your hard constraints are:

- Every station must be on a point. A points are on a grid with a distance of X between points (I'd make this static on 2cm)
- There should not be 2 stations on the same spot
- There should be enough room to draw the station label. Note that the label can be assigned different directions from the point to which the station is assigned.
- There should be enough room to draw the subway lines.

Looks like your soft constraints are:

- For each station, minimize the actually geographical location distance to the point assigned to the station.

Then throw something like Drools Planner on it, [here's an example of hard and soft constraints for nurse rostering](http://www.slideshare.net/ge0ffrey/pushing-the-rule-engine-to-its-limits-with-drools-planner-parisjug-20101109/13).